# Onclick change image source in another div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have 3 small divs, that when you click on I'd like to popuplate a larger div at the top of my page, only issue is i can't get it working at all and I've no idea why.

Im trying to update

```
$('.highlight-image').on('click', function (e) {

console.log('clicked');

var currImg = $(this).find('.imageHolder').children('img').attr('src');
var currP = $(this).find('blockquote').text;

var targetImg = $('.featuredTestimonial img');
var targetName = $('.featuredTestimonial h2');
var targetP = $('.featuredTestimonial p');

$('.featuredTestimonial p').text = currP;
$('.featuredTestimonial img').attr('src'); = currImg;

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6qcpg/2/

Comment: `.text()` function wants a parameter inside the parenthesis, you can't assign the value using `.text = val`

Comment: There are couple of mistakes, Fixed demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/6qcpg/4/)**.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
$('.featuredTestimonial img').attr('src'); = currImg;
```

To

```
$('.featuredTestimonial img').attr('src', currImg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.featuredTestimonial p').text(currP);
$('.featuredTestimonial img').attr('src', currImg);
```

instead of

```
$('.featuredTestimonial p').text = currP;
$('.featuredTestimonial img').attr('src'); = currImg;
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6qcpg/5/)

Answer (score 1):

use it

**Working http://jsfiddle.net/JFTTe/**

```
 $('.highlight-image').on('click', function(e) {
     var currImg = $(this).find('.imageHolder').children('img').attr('src');
     var currP = $(this).find('blockquote').text();

     var targetImg = $('.featuredTestimonial img');
     var targetName = $('.featuredTestimonial h2');
     var targetP = $('.featuredTestimonial p');

     $('.featuredTestimonial p').text(currP);
     $('.featuredTestimonial img').attr('src', currImg);
 });
```